# How to setup windows authentication between non-domain servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, sql-server, iis

How can I setup windows authentication between a Windows Server 2003 running IIS6 and Windows Server 2008 running SQL Server 2008, when both servers are standalone non-domain servers.

I want the sites on my 2003 server to connect to the databases on the 2008 server, but I don't want to store credentials in the connection strings.

Answer (score 4):

Rather simple, create two accounts that are identical on both machines (same username/password).  Set the app pool identity to that user and bam you have integrated authentication.  That is all...

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Now go answer this questions: http://serverfault.com/questions/68748